# Why can't we to mark as WriteCombined already existing memory region by using `cudaHostRegister()`?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, posix, gpgpu

In CUDA SDK function [`cudaHostAlloc()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c.html#g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c) for allocation new memory region can use flags:

- cudaHostAllocDefault (**default** - 0 and causes cudaHostAlloc() to emulate cudaMallocHost())
- cudaHostAllocPortable
- cudaHostAllocMapped
- cudaHostAllocWriteCombined

To mark memory region that already allocated we can use [`cudaHostRegister()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141.html#g36b9fe28f547f28d23742e8c7cd18141) with flags:

- 0 (**default**)
- cudaHostRegisterPortable
- cudaHostRegisterMapped

Why we can mark memory WriteCombined when allocating it by flag `cudaHostAllocWriteCombined` by using `cudaHostAlloc()`, but can't mark as WriteCombined already existing memory region by using `cudaHostRegister()`?

Already allocated memory we must will mark only through the **POSIX** function [`set_memory_wc()`](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/pat.txt#127)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not know of any APIs that could change the cacheability of an existing VA range until you referenced `set_memory_wc()`. Such an operation would be extremely expensive due to all the cache flushes and TLB shootdowns that would be required; and the memory would basically be unreadable until you found some way to unmark it as WC.

Why are you trying to use WC memory?  On pre-i7 (Nehalem) CPUs, WC had slightly higher transfer performance (IIRC) because it inhibited snooping of PCI Express traffic to and from the memory.  But on Nehalem and later CPUs, I don't know of any application that has concretely demonstrated a benefit from WC memory.

Comment: Big thanks! Yes, I want to increase performance by using WC-memory region and `MOV[NT]Q` (NT - none temporary) stream SSE-instructions, such as writen here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/increasing-memory-throughput-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4-streaming-load  But can you give me a link where have said that starting from **Nehalem** WC and stream NT-SSE does not matter?

Comment: It's an observation that the CUDA team made when Nehalem processors first came out - the main developer-visible way it presents itself is that pageable memcpy's became very nearly as fast as pinned ones.  It's discussed briefly in The CUDA Handbook (5.1.4).

Here's another take on the matter: http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/write-combining-is-not-your-friend/

Comment: Thanks! Clear. WC-memory made ​​sense on processors with FSB, because snooping through FSB work slowly: http://books.google.ru/books?id=ynydqKP225EC&pg=PR9&lpg=PR9&dq=cuda+handbook+Chapter+5.1.4&source=bl&ots=5j06O0PCCH&sig=pddrqKs7B9bxklXr_LEBxKf7ZxM&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=zqhSUruWL-Gu4ATr_oHABw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=cuda%20handbook%20Chapter%205.1.4&f=false