# Trying to use: cudaHostAllocWriteCombined flag but I'm getting invalid argument when I try cudaMemcpy

Tags: cuda, nvidia, memcpy

First off I'd like to say I really do like the CUDA documentation it's really great and resourceful although I'm finding it hard to find out what is supported in what version. I'm using CUDA driver version 5.0 with compute capability 2.0 and was wondering if cudaHostAllocWriteCombined is supported?

In my code:

```
float *d_data, h_data;
h_data = new float[A];

assert(cudaHostAlloc((void **)&d_data, A * sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocWriteCombined) == cudaSuccess);

cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, A * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (err != cudaSuccess)
{
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

error returns invalid argument, however if I use cudaHostAllocDefault it seems to work fine, I understand how it works fast writing slow reading and that's why I would like to use it.

Comment: cudaHostAllocWriteCombined might be 2.2 source:

http://www.naic.edu/~phil/hardware/nvidia/doc/src/simpleZeroCopy/doc/CUDA2.2PinnedMemoryAPIs.pdf

page 10

Comment: It's doubtful that write combining [is useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197671/why-cant-we-to-mark-as-writecombined-already-existing-memory-region-by-using-c) on newer processor architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `h_data` is incorrect.  `new` returns a *pointer*, which should be assigned to the correct variable type.  Replace `h_data` with `*h_data` in your declaration, and your code will be more-or-less correct, and `cudaMemcpy` should not throw an invalid argument error.

The following complete code shows the correction and compiles and runs without error for me on CUDA 6:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#define A 1024
int main(){

  float *d_data, *h_data;
  h_data = new float[A];

  cudaError_t err = cudaHostAlloc((void **)&d_data, A * sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocWriteCombined);
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::cout << "cudaHostAlloc fail " << std::endl;
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  err = cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, A * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (err != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::cout << "cudaMemcpy fail"  << std::endl;
    std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```